# How to format .bib for US Code legal citations

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago, legal-style

I'm looking for the correct format to fully flush out the .bib entry for "17 U.S.C. 107 - Limitations on exclusive rights: Fair use" that needs to be presented bluebook style. I'm using

```
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{referances.bib}
```

And the output looks pretty close, but I'm still trying to figure out how to write the entries in to the .bib file. I don't know if I should use an @Legislation or @Jurisdiction for this, but I'd like to learn to do it right. I've read through the biblatex-chicago info, and it's not totally obvious for many cases, (pun intended). Are there any example .bib files on US legal writing available to get an idea of the format?

There are sites with all the info, like https://www.govinfo.gov/app/details/USCODE-2010-title17/USCODE-2010-title17-chap1-sec107/summary but, I didn't find any with direct download to .bib file for biblatex. I guess, alternatively, if there is a good site that has links to download biblatex fomated info, that'd be great also.

Comment: I'd say it's `@legislation`. `biblatex-chicago` comes with a few example documents (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc), you may be interested in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/cms-legal-sample.tex and http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/legal-test.bib

Comment: Thanks moewe, did a lot of example reading and I gave it a try. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For now, I'm going with:

```
@Legislation{UScode17sect107,
  bookpagination = {section},
  entrysubtype = {usa},
  title =    {U.S. Code Title 17 - Copyrights},
  journaltitle = {Code of Laws of the United States of America},
  shortjournal = {USC},
  subtitle =  {Limitations on Exclusive Rights: Fair Use},
  shorttitle = {USC 17 Section 107},
  volume =   17,
  number =   {1-4},
  pages =    107,
  titleaddon = {Fair Use},
}
```

But I may want to improve it.